# Why webview is not supporting to make phone call? I have loaded google search page and tried to call from that search result but it gives error

Tags: android-studio, url, webview, call, google-search

In my app, webpage loads google search but it is not allowing to call from search result. It gives error

```
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_hospital_map);
    webView= findViewById(R.id.nearbyWebView);
    this.setTitle("Nearby Hospitals");
   // String url= "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospital&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml";
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospital&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml");
}
```

webview in my app:

[image: image 1]

after clicking call icon it gives error:

[image: image 2]